# Snowflake query for limit/top with condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In `Snowflake` i was trying to limit the number of rows based on a condition. query is generated from the application.

Logic I was trying to achieve.

- if the condition matches, then select all rows in the table
- else limit to the given row number

let's consider `a` as row number count, if it is `-1` then I want to retrieve all the rows.

```
SELECT * FROM "PUBLIC".TABLE1 LIMIT ( 
CASE WHEN a = -1
THEN
  -- no limit
ELSE 
 a
```

`a` will be resolved to number by application. Is this kind of operation is possible in Snowflake?

> Above query is not working in Snowflake, just added it to specify the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using the [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) and [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) functions:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT SEQ4()+1 AS val, 100 AS a
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000)) AS t
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val) AS rn
  FROM sample_data
QUALIFY rn <= IFF(a = -1, rn, a);
```

Result: `100 rows`

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT SEQ4()+1 AS val, -1 AS a
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000)) AS t
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val) AS rn
  FROM sample_data
QUALIFY rn <= IFF(a = -1, rn, a);
```

Result: `1000 rows` -- no limit, all rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting.html) (in public preview):

```
create or replace table test (a int);
insert into test values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
select * from test;

create or replace procedure dynamic_limit(limit int)
returns table(a int)
language sql
as
$$
    declare
        query string default 'SELECT * FROM TEST'; 
    begin
        IF (limit > 0) THEN
            query := :query || ' LIMIT ' || :limit;
        END IF;
    
        let res resultset default (execute immediate :query);
        return table(res);
    end;
$$;

call dynamic_limit(-1);
+---+
| A |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
+---+

call dynamic_limit(0);
+---+
| A |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
+---+

call dynamic_limit(1);
+---+
| A |
|---|
| 1 |
+---+

call dynamic_limit(4);
+---+
| A |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is good, I flipped it to have a session variable just so there is a tiny bit of independence

```
SET A = 5;
/* session variable to "control" */

WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT
    SEQ4() AS val
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
)
/* CTE for data */

SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val) AS RN
FROM sample_data
QUALIFY RN <= IFF($a = -1, rn, $a);
```

| VAL | RN |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |

we can however move the ROW_NUMBER into the QUALIFY by negating the sign of ROW_NUMBER and some sign flipping, and thus instead of needing to know the current rows, or max rows `rn` we can compare to zero:

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM sample_data AS sd
QUALIFY ($a - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sd.val)) * $a >= 0;
```

| VAL |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

this is working because our row numbers are going from -1 -> -infinity but we take this from a limit (-1 or 5) and then multiplying that by limit which for negative value flips the sign to all positive, and for positive limit does nothing to the number of values that are positive

which can be seen in this working code:

```
SELECT *
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val) as rn
   ,(5 - rn) * 5
   ,(-1 - rn) * -1
FROM sample_data
```

which show how the math works out for 5 OR -1

| VAL | RN | (5 - RN) * 5 | (-1 - RN) * -1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 20 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 15 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 | -5 | 7 |
| 6 | 7 | -10 | 8 |
| 7 | 8 | -15 | 9 |
| 8 | 9 | -20 | 10 |
| 9 | 10 | -25 | 11 |